# Characterisation of essentially algebraic theories with a fixed set of sorts

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, locally-presentable-categories, algebraic-theory

It is well known (e.g. Palmgren–Vickers's [Partial Horn logic and cartesian categories](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Epalmgren/partialalgebras_pre.pdf)) that many-sorted essentially algebraic theories (equivalently partial Horn theories / quasi-equational theories / cartesian theories) may be characterised as small finitely complete categories. Here, the set of sorts is not fixed, and varies according to the category.

For a fixed set $S$, is there a known category theoretic characterisation of $S$-sorted essentially algebraic theories, so that (for example) one-sorted essentially algebraic theories may be characterised as certain finitely complete categories?

(Note that I am assuming that the equivalence between quasi-equational/partial Horn/essentially algebraic/cartesian theories continues to hold when the set of sorts is fixed. If this is not the case, I shall update my question accordingly.)

---

There are some related results in the literature – I've listed the ones I know of below – but I have not found a characterisation for essentially algebraic theories.

- Keane proves in [Abstract Horn theories](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0061292) that a small category is equivalent to a one-sorted Horn theory iff it is finitely complete and has an object $I$ which is $\mathcal M$-injective and such that every object is a $\mathcal M$-subobject of $I^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, for $\mathcal M$ a left-exact class of monomorphisms.
- Adámek and Porst prove in [Algebraic Theories of Quasivarieties](http://www.math.uni-bremen.de/%7Eporst/dvis/AlgTheocorr.pdf) that a small category is equivalent to the theory of a one-sorted quasivariety iff it is finitely complete and has an object $I$ which is regular injective and such that every object is a regular subobject of $I^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.
- $S$-sorted algebraic theories are well-known to be equivalent to strict identity-on-objects finite product-preserving functors from the free category with finite products on $S$.

---

I should note that a characterisation is deducible from the results of Di Liberti–Loregian–Nester–Sobociński's [Functorial Semantics for Partial Theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.06644), as the finitely complete categories induced by (Cauchy complete) $S$-sorted partial algebraic theories; however, this is not a very direct characterisation and I am hoping for one along the lines of the previous examples.

Comment: What precisely is an "$S$-sorted" algebraic theory? E.g. we frequently distinguish between "1-sorted" and "many-sorted" theories, but depending on how you define things, even a "1-sorted" theory typically has infinitely many sorts (one for each cartesian power of the "home sort"). For me, the default notion of "algebraic theory" is "an essentially small category with finite products" -- if I want to restrict my algebraic theories to be $S$-sorted in the sense you intend, do I need to assume that the "commutative monoid" of objects under $\times$ is free on the set $S$ or something?

Comment: @TimCampion: *$S$-sorted algebraic theory* here means a "cartesian category $\mathscr A$ together with a strict identity-on-objects finite product-preserving functor $\mathbb A(S) \to \mathscr A$", where $\mathbb A(S)$ is the free strict cartesian category on the set $A$, as in Bénabou's *Structures algébriques dans les catégories*.

Comment: That makes perfect sense in the algebraic case. Looking back at the question, I was asking for the wrong clarification, because you're interested in the essentially algebraic case. What is an $S$-sorted essentially algebraic theory? This seems less clear to me, and I'm not sure I've seen a definition given before other than just taking $S$ to be the set of objects of one's finitely-complete category, _contra_ the algebraic case. Maybe you could take the set of objects of a limit sketch, but this also doesn't really agree with the algebraic case.

Comment: So I guess what I'm saying is that the issue anticipated in the parenthetical third paragraph of the question is indeed an issue as far as I can see. Unfortunately I don't know what the resolution is. Possibly there's more than one reasonable inequivalent way to make sense of it.

Comment: @TimCampion: a categorical formulation is not obvious (which is the main motivation for the question), so for the purposes of this question, an $S$-sorted essentially algebraic theory is defined syntactically (i.e. as [quadruple](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+algebraic+theory) $\Gamma = (\Sigma, E, \Sigma_t, \mathrm{Def})$): here, there is an explicit set of sorts.

Comment: Let me note that there is an intuitive characterisation of the categories representing these theories: they are those finitely complete categories $\mathscr C$ with an injective-on-objects functor $F : S \to \mathscr C$, such that every object is the equaliser of a finite product of objects in the image of $F$. This is really the definition I want to capture, but it is not obvious to me how to make this precise in a manner as elegant as the examples in the question.

Comment: Hm. It seems to me that the intuitive characterization you gave is right in line with the theorems of Keane and of Adamek-Porst that you discuss. What more could one want? E.g. when $S$ is a singleton (the case where the comparison makes the most sense), the intuitive characterization is almost the same as the Adamek-Porst one, minus the regular-injectivity condition.

Comment: In Sec 5 of our paper we say how to pass from an essentially algebraic theory, presented as a partial equational theory to a DCRC, then one can go to DCRC to categories with finite limits taking cc. I am not sure one can do better than this.

Comment: @TimCampion: I feel the condition that "every object is the equaliser of a finite product of objects in the image of $F$" is rather inelegant, compared to the structured subobject conditions of the examples.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: I accept this is certainly a possibility.

Comment: I feel that there should be an OFS on Lex whose right class are the fully faithful functors; the left class L ought to be something like injective-on-objects finite-limit-cogenerating functors (i.e. every object in the codomain is a finite limit of objects in the image). This would act as the lex analogue of the bo/ff factorisation on finite product-preserving functors. The S-sorted essentially algebraic theories would then be the L-functors out of the free finitely complete category on S. I haven't figured out how to show such an OFS exists yet; I'd hope there was an elegant proof.

Comment: @varkor. Yes you can. See Sec 10.1 in John Bourke's PhD Thesis: https://www.math.muni.cz/~bourkej/papers/JohnBThesis.pdf.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: thanks, this looks perfect.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: on closer reading, the hypotheses of Sec. 10.1 don't seem to apply in this case, the main examples there being categories of algebras for strongly finitary 2-monads. However, $\mathbf{Lex}$ is only finitary.

Comment: One should really invoke John here to see how much one can sharpen his result.